# How can I get user information after successful login and show ir inn a drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

- List item

I'm trying to get information after storing information from successful login and displaying that information in a `UserAccountsDrawerHeader`.

But without using a future builder or list builder.

example:: accountName:Text("info name from database")

how could that be done?

help would be greatly appreciated.

code:

```
       -- Services--
         Future <List>InfoCabeceraDrawer() async{
            Map<String, String> headers = {
              'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
              'Charset':'utf-8'
            };
        
            var Url= Uri.parse("http://");
            final response = await http.get((Url),headers: headers);
            print(response.body);
            return productDrawerFromJson(response.body);
          }
        
        --- Model--
        List productCabeceraDrawerFromJson(String str) => List<CabeceraDrawerModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => CabeceraDrawerModel.fromJson(x)));// con esto hago el get
        
        class CabeceraDrawerModel{
        
          String UsuarioPk;
          String FotoUsuario;
          String CorreoUsuario;
          String NombreUsuario;
        
          CabeceraDrawerModel({this.UsuarioPk,this.FotoUsuario,this.NombreUsuario,this.CorreoUsuario});
        
          factory CabeceraDrawerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
            return CabeceraDrawerModel(
                UsuarioPk: parsedJson['Usu'],
                FotoUsuario:parsedJson['im'],
                NombreUsuario: parsedJson['Usuar'],
                CorreoUsuario:parsedJson['Usuario_C']
            );
          }
        
        }
        
        -- front--
        
     @override
      void initState() {
        
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
 accountName: Text("show information data base"),
    accountEmail:Text(""),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the State management approaches that Flutter mentioned [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).